# try/except clause and numeric range condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new at python and doing the Coursera specialization "Python for everybody".

One of the assignments is about prompting a user to enter a score from 0.0 to 1.0 to convert it to a grade. If the input isn't numerical or within the range, it should give an error message.

I use the try, except clause but I can't seem to figure out how to get the numerical conditions working in the try block.

I'm assuming this line would work in the try block "S<=1.0 or S>=0.0", but it doesn't. When I enter 1.2 for instance, it gets ignored and I get an A grade instead of the error message.

I can get it done by placing the range condition as an "if" outside of the try, except clause, but that seems like unnecessary lines of code.

How do I do this right? And overall, how can I make this entire code better?

The working code below:

```
Score = input("Enter Score from 0.0 to 1.0:")
try:
    S = float(Score)
except:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input from 0.0 to 1.0")
    quit()
if S>1.0 or S<0.0:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input from 0.0 to 1.0")
    quit()
elif S>=0.9:
    print("A")
elif S>=0.8:
    print("B")
elif S>=0.7:
    print("C")
elif S>=0.6:
    print("D")
elif S>=0.0:
    print("F")
quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `except` without explicit exception type. If you want to include the range check in the try-block, the if have to raise it's own exception:

```
score = input("Enter Score from 0.0 to 1.0:")
try:
    score = float(score)
    if not 0.0 <= score <= 1.0:
        raise ValueError()
except ValueError:
    print("Error, please enter numeric input from 0.0 to 1.0")
else:
    for boundary, grade in [(0.9, 'A'), (0.8, 'B'), (0.7, 'C'), (0.6, 'D')]:
        if score >= boundary:
            break
    else:
        grade = 'F'
    print(grade)
```

Comment: Wow, I'll look into this. It looks like how I would have the better code in mind. Thank you very much!